# Format string date and time using MomentJs in React project

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have api that provides the date and time and I need to format it. Its a react project and I am using momentJs. I am open to other methods.

Currently I get error that invalid date

```
// this is the exact string that is coming from api
const fromApi = "2022-08-23 00:10:29 +0000"

return(
  <div>
    {moment(fromApi).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}
  </div>
```

Comment: In what exact format do you need the date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While parsing the date you need also pass the format your date string is in.
I can see that this is a react code I would suggest you declare a variable to store the date and use it in your JSX.
For Example:

```
const fromApi = "2022-08-23 00:10:29 +0000"
const someday = moment("2022-08-23 00:10:29 +0000","YYYY-MM-DD");

return(
  <div>
    {someday}
  </div>
```

This would do but if you want to **optimize the code** then you must use useMemo to cache someday value  so that it is not re calculated every time you call function.
Just Like:

```
const someday = useMemo(()=>moment("2022-08-23 00:10:29 +0000","YYYY-MM-DD"),[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I work ok with your code, i think you should check **fromApi** from api before render to **moment()**, because **fromApi** able undefined.

```js
const fromApi = "2022-08-23 00:10:29 +0000"

return(
  <div>
    {fromApi && moment(fromApi).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}
  </div>
```